# How to change colour of the survival curves in a survival ctree object r

Tags: r, colors, party

I am doing a survival ctree with party package (R software) and i would like to have coloured survival curves in the terminal panel.

```
fitform <- Surv(delai_efs ,evt_efs) ~ age + sexer + ... + bmiins + tailler + 

tree = ctree(formula = fitform, data = taclfknn, controls = ctree_control(teststat = "max", testtype = "Teststatistic")

plot(tree)
```

I tried to change the source code integrating additional arguments like color or using `gp = gpar(col=...)` but i failed...

[image]

Any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution for function `ctree` from `partykit` package.

You can specify plotting parameters for different types of terminal nodes. All parameter for your case can be found `?node_surv`

To change a colour of survival curve:

```
plot(tree, terminal_panel=node_surv(tree, col="green"))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out how to solve this and where to find the documentation. Instead of specifying the whole `terminal_panel` argument, you can also just specify the corresponding arguments (`tp_args`). For example, after running `example("ctree", package = "partykit")` you could do: `plot(GBSG2ct, tp_args = list(col = "blue"))`

Comment: @AchimZeileis : Thanks for all too !

Comment: when i run : plot(tree, terminal_panel=node_surv(tree, col="green")) , i don't know why it does not work, and i have this error message : Error in survfitKM(X, newY, casewt, ...) : unused argument (col = "blue")  and when i also run plot(tree, tp_args = list(col = "blue")) i get also this error message @Lstat : Thanks for all !!

Comment: It seems that you are using the old `party` implementation rather than the new (and more flexible) `partykit` package. See `vignette("ctree", package = "partykit")` for some background information on the important changes between the packages.

Comment: @AchimZeileis, Thank you for your response. Yes, i used the `party` package but now i am using the `partykit` package with a really simple tree ` tree=ctree(formula=fitform,data = taclfknn)` and then i run `plot(tree,tp_args = list(col = "blue"))` but i would like different colours for each different survival curve in the terminal_panel

Comment: @S.Zebachi I'm not sure what you mean here and your example is not reproducible. Having different colors _within_ the same terminal panel would only make sense if there were several lines in the same panel. And having different colors _across_ terminal panels also does not seem to be very useful. Or maybe you want all lines within the same plot (outside of a tree)? In any case, I would argue that this is a new question and not suitable for the comments section which is already too long. And my feeling is that Lstat has answered your original question so that accepting it would be appropriate.

Comment: @AchimZeileis,yes, i wanted to have different colors within the same terminal panel just for the design and i finally managed in modifying the source code for having that. So thanks !!

Comment: Thanks to @Lstat for your help and sorry to have accepted late, i'am new in this community and don't know well how it works...